# Sucker_punch errors or not properly running background jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sucker-punch

I have a  Classified Model where i use a after_create callback for checking keywords of a user and send email notification.

this email it is send by a Background Job using ActiveJobs and Sucker_punch as background driver.

I see in the logs 3 jobs are being queued:

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 8843b126-18fe-4cc1-b2f3-41141a199bcb) to SuckerPunch(mailers) with arguments: "NotificationMailer", "keyword_found", "deliver_now", gid://clasificados/Classified/233, gid://clasificados/User/1

[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 591ce6eb-34d1-4381-93ea-4b708171996f) to SuckerPunch(mailers) with arguments: "NotificationMailer", "keyword_found", "deliver_now", gid://clasificados/Classified/234, gid://clasificados/User/1

[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 3b1de0ea-f48d-41f2-be5a-8f5b2369b8ea) to SuckerPunch(mailers) with arguments: "NotificationMailer", "keyword_found", "deliver_now", gid://clasificados/Classified/235, gid://clasificados/User/1
```

but i only received **2** emails...

i see in logs errors like:

```
Terminating 6 actors...
Terminating task: type=:finalizer, meta={:method_name=>:__shutdown__}, status=:receiving
    Celluloid::TaskFiber backtrace unavailable. Please try `Celluloid.task_class = Celluloid::TaskThread` if you need backtraces here.`

Terminating task: type=:call, meta={:method_name=>:perform}, status=:callwait
    Celluloid::TaskFiber backtrace unavailable. Please try `Celluloid.task_class = Celluloid::TaskThread` if you need backtraces here.
Celluloid::PoolManager: async call `perform` aborted!
Celluloid::Task::TerminatedError: task was terminated
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:34:in `terminate'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:345:in `each'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:345:in `cleanup'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:329:in `shutdown'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:164:in `run'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:130:in `block in start'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/thread_handle.rb:13:in `block in initialize'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor_system.rb:32:in `block in get_thread'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:130:in `call'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:130:in `block in create'
Terminating task: type=:call, meta={:method_name=>:perform}, status=:callwait
    Celluloid::TaskFiber backtrace unavailable. Please try `Celluloid.task_class = Celluloid::TaskThread` if you need backtraces here.
Celluloid::PoolManager: async call `perform` aborted!
Celluloid::Task::TerminatedError: task was terminated
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:34:in `terminate'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:345:in `each'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:345:in `cleanup'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:329:in `shutdown'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:164:in `run'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:130:in `block in start'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/thread_handle.rb:13:in `block in initialize'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor_system.rb:32:in `block in get_thread'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:130:in `call'
    /home/angel/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:130:in `block in create'
Terminating task: type=:finalizer, meta={:method_name=>:__shutdown__}, status=:receiving
    Celluloid::TaskFiber backtrace unavailable. Please try `Celluloid.task_class = Celluloid::TaskThread` if you need backtraces here.
```

Model:

```
class Classified < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :find_matched_keywords

  def find_matched_keywords
    User.all.each do |u|
      u.profile.keywords.scan(/[a-zA-Z\d]+/) do |k|
        if self[:content].downcase.include?(k)
          SendEmailJob.new.async.perform(self, u)
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Job:

```
class SendEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  queue_as :default

  def perform(classified, user)
    NotificationMailer.keyword_found(classified, user).deliver_later
  end
end
```

any idea what could be happening?

thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i changed to sidekiq...
problem solved.